# Word interop error: 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: c#, office-interop

There are lots of questions about this error but I cannot find the answer that suits me.
I am using word interop, and on my development machine it works.
When I do a release build and run it, I get this error;

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered.

On solution I have tried is to change the project properties to release to 64 bit CPU.
The build server is a 64 bit enironment, Windows 2008.

What should I try next? Should I reset the project properties to any CPU?

Comment: COM *should* be CPU-bit agnostic, maybe if you post the CLSID someone may help you, are you distributing the .net interop assemblies with your product? does your client have the right version of office?

Comment: Change the project properties to 32-bit (x86). Nobody uses 64-bit office :-)

Comment: @Bond: COM is not CPU-bit agnostic. 32-bit and 64-bit applications look for COM objects in different places in the registry. 32-bit application will not find 64-bit COM objects and 64-bit applications will not find 32-bit COM objects. A COM object can register in both but that is rare and office is definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

Change your build settings on the starting executable to make an x86 version (32 bit). Office has only been available as 32bit version (until recently) so odds are that you are running a 32bit version of office.  Any remanining assemblies that you references may be ANY_CPU. They will load as 32 bit into a 32 bit process or 64 bit into a 64 bit process. An ANY_CPU executable will load as 64 bit on a 64 bit system and 32 bit on a 32 bit system. That will not allow you to access a 32bit office install on a 64 bit system.

Comment: I changed my build settings as you suggest but I still get the same problem. However what is also true is that Microsoft Office is not installed on the build server, should it be?

Comment: Are you doign anything in your build (like unit tests) that would cause an attempt to create an instance of word ?

Comment: I take a word document as a template, inject some words into a placeholder and save it is a new word document, like a mail merge. So I use an instance of word in my code.

Comment: Yes, but your build server would typically just takes your source code and builds the executable. It typically would not run teh built executable unless you had some automated testing as part of the build.

Comment: I am not clear what the implications are of that in relation to fixing this.

Comment: Are you receiving the com excpetion on your build server or on a different box ?

Comment: I may be wrong to think this, but I think of the build server as the server I am publishing the app to, the test server. tfs is on another server. The exception appears on the test server.

Comment: Is MS Word installed on your test server ?

Comment: No it isn't. Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes. The message means that the word com object deos not exist on that box. If your test server is 64bit, then you may need to build you executable as 32bit as most version of word are 32bit. (Office 2010 and Office 2013 have an x64 option).